# MySQL LEFT join alias issue

Tags: mysql, join, alias

(edited) I am trying to write an sql join.

```
SELECT a.id, 
                   a.name,
                   c.name AS 'gender',
                   a.email,
                   a.phone, 
                   a.address,
                   b.name AS 'level', 
                   a.level_id
            FROM ms_user a 
            LEFT JOIN lt_user_level b 
            ON a.level_id = b.id 
            LEFT JOIN lt_user_gender c 
            ON a.gender_id = c.id 
            WHERE a.id LIKE '%".$id."%'
            AND a.name LIKE '%".$name."%' 
            AND 'gender' LIKE '%".$gender."%'
            AND a.email LIKE '%".$email."%'                 
            AND a.phone LIKE '%".$phone."%'                                 
            AND a.address LIKE '%".$address."%'
            AND 'level' LIKE '%".$level."%'                                                 
            AND a.status <> 'D'
```

Now I would like to search data by gender and level. but, it's not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backquotes if you want to use it with column names. Also you cannot use the alias name in the where clause(*Correctly pointed by Barmar.*)

Try this

```
SELECT a.id, 
               a.name,
               c.name AS `gender`,
               a.email,
               a.phone, 
               a.address,
               b.name AS `level`, 
               a.level_id
        FROM ms_user a 
        LEFT JOIN lt_user_level b 
        ON a.level_id = b.id 
        LEFT JOIN lt_user_gender c 
        ON a.gender_id = c.id 
        WHERE a.id LIKE '%".$id."%'
        AND a.name LIKE '%".$name."%' 
        AND c.name LIKE '%".$gender."%'
        AND a.email LIKE '%".$email."%'                 
        AND a.phone LIKE '%".$phone."%'                                 
        AND a.address LIKE '%".$address."%'
        AND  b.name LIKE '%".$level."%'                                                 
        AND a.status <> 'D'
```

Comment: You can't refer to aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the alias name in the where condition and you cant do that you have to use the complete column name or use having clause if you want to use the column alias

```
AND 'gender' LIKE '%".$gender."%'
```

to

```
AND c.name LIKE '%".$gender."%'
```

Similarly for

```
 AND 'level' LIKE '%".$level."%'
```

to

```
 AND b.name LIKE '%".$level."%'
```